# Looking for an API call to fetch all domain-wide delegations within my Google Admin Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-cloud-identity, cloud-security

For security reasons we are looking to automate calls into Google Admin Console (Workspace) in order to fetch, once a day, all the domain-wide delegations within our Google Admin console, the call needs to provide the client ID and the scopes of each API Client.

Is there a call to fetch that information **without manually accessing the Admin Console**?

[Domain-wide Delegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7qcX.png)

I read through the Google Admin SDK docs (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk) and was unable to find such API call.

Comment: I am not aware of any APIs for Workspace or Cloud IAM that provide details on Domain Wide Delegation. You can get the service account OAuth Client ID with this [API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts#ServiceAccount) but not the settings if delegation is enabled. I could be wrong, so I am only posting a comment.